# try to split the row of a csv output

Tags: python, csv

Now I am writing some data into a csv file. I directly write a list to a row of a csv file, like below:

```
with open("files/data.csv", "wb") as f_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(f_csv,delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(flux_inteplt)        ## here flux_inteplt is a list
```

But when I read the data like below:

```
with open('files/data.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        parts = row.split(",")
        print parts[0]
```

It has some problem `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Does anyone has some idea how to approach to this problem?

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: I believe the first line of the csv file. There are total 45 lines.

Comment: `csv` has already split the row for you, on the basis of the `delimiter` you supplied; you have a list of strings for each line, not the single string you'd get if you iterated directly over the file

Comment: The reader object contains the list of your csv rows so you can not use `split` method for it.If  you want to print the fist item just print `row[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('us-cities.csv','rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    str1 = ''.join(row) #Convert list into string
    parts = str1.split(",")
    print parts[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

row is already a `list`, when you iterate over the reader object you get a list of values split by the delimiter you pass, just use each row:

```
for row in reader:
   print row[0] # first element from each row
```

If you have  comma separated  values use `delimiter=','` not `delimiter=' '`, which based on the fact you use `csv.writer(f_csv,delimiter = ',')` when writing  means you have. The delimiter you pass when writing is what is used to delimit each element from your input iterable so when reading you need to use the same delimiter if you want to get the same output.

Comment: @HuanianZhang, no prob, you're welcome, can I ask why you are using a delimiter of `" "` then splitting on a comma?

Comment: I copied delimiter' ' from somewhere, then I do not know why the comma is missing~

Answer (score 0):

row is already a list. No need to split (:

Comment: Thanks. Since I want the first element of each row. The previous answer works.